# Optimising keyword retrieval using SQL Server's Full-Text Search

Tags: sql-server, optimization, full-text-search, keyword-search

I have a SQL Server Full-Text Search indexing two columns in one of my tables.

I am pulling out suggested keywords from a web front-end based on user's input. Such that entering a phrase like **'ban'** would yield words such as **banana**, **banish**, **urban**, **husband**, etc. The user would then click on one of these words to confirm their choice, or add further letters to narrow down their search.

I have the following number of total keywords, as shown by the following query:

```
SELECT COUNT(*) FROM sys.dm_fts_index_keywords ( DB_ID(), OBJECT_ID('Search'))
```

> 217,998

So, when querying the keywords I have a query like below:

```
SELECT TOP 10 *, display_term, document_count 
FROM sys.dm_fts_index_keywords ( DB_ID(), OBJECT_ID('Search'))
WHERE column_id=5 
AND keyword != 0xFF 
AND display_term like '%ban%' 
AND display_term NOT LIKE 'nn%'
```

However, this currently takes circa 30 seconds to run! Clearly this is far too slow to be of any use.

So, as a way of a work around I have created my own **keywords** table to store my keywords. Whenever I add content to my full-text search table, I run a query below to find out which keywords will be indexed:

```
SELECT display_term AS Term, COUNT(display_term) AS [Count] 
FROM sys.dm_fts_parser('"There are many types of fruit, including apples, bananas and cherries." ', 1033, 0, 0)
WHERE display_term NOT LIKE 'nn%' 
AND special_term NOT IN ('Noise Word', 'End of Sentence')
GROUP BY display_term
```

I then take these words and store them into my own keywords table, for later use by the web front end described above. This is much quicker.

However, I can't help feeling that I shouldn't need to create a workaround and that finding keywords is something that many people would need to be doing.

I have searched for other methods, tables, or other functionality contained within SQL Server, but all to no avail.

I have also looked into indexing the `sys.dm_fts_index_keywords` table. However, searching for the word "indexing" is problematic due to the nature of subject matter.

Does anyone have another method that is quick to execute, and hopefully also requires less programmatic intervention?

Comment: Full text won't help you, it's designed for whole words. Can't do better than @PaulWhite 's [Trigram Search](https://sqlperformance.com/2017/09/sql-performance/sql-server-trigram-wildcard-search)